# How do I complete a commit in Git Bash after entering the message?

Tags: git, git-bash

I am new to Git and trying to lean the revert command. After reverting a specific commit the following screen appears. As per tutorials Crtl-X not working. What should I do??

[image: pic Result]

Comment: FYI, a revert is just another commit. You're simply committing the inverse of the previous commit.

Comment: You should write a comment or bug to the author of the tutorial--they assumed that your system editor was nano when it could very well be vim (as mentioned here). The author probably had a configuration where nano was their editor without realizing that this wasn't universal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+exit+vim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're asking how to exit edit mode in Git Bash. Type colon (`:`), then enter `wq` for "write, quit".